# loginPopup from @azure/msal-browser not working on Microsoft Teams desktop application

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal

I'm creating a Tab for Microsoft Teams and I use loginPopup from the `@azure/msal-browser` to authenticate. In the web/browser application works just fine but I installed the tab in the desktop application and it doesn't work and the following error fires:

```
    at EventEmitter.ipcRenderer.sendSync (<anonymous>:1840:18)
    at Object.exports.invokeSync (<anonymous>:1814:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:3360:22)
    at Object.require.35../../common/atom-binding-setup (<anonymous>:3513:4)
    at o (<anonymous>:2:273)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:439)
    at <anonymous>:2:468
    at Function.PopupHandler.openSizedPopup (index.es.js:10451)
    at PublicClientApplication.ClientApplication.acquireTokenPopup (index.es.js:11102)
    at PublicClientApplication.loginPopup (index.es.js:12022)
```

Not sure if something about the msal library or something about the electron wrapper for the desktop app. Some directions on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

for teams Tabs please do not roll your own authentication based on browsers, as your tab will need to work in browsers , but also Windows / Mac OS / linux / iOS and Android.

Instead take a looks at the documentation for Teams Tab Authentication or,
even better AAD Single Sign On

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso

Comment: The same SSO authentication mechanism can now also be leveraged by Teams Bots

Answer (score 1):

LoginPopup won't work because Teams surfaces it's own authentication popup to provide the ability to integrate MSAL or similar, so you end up needed to do LoginRedirect, *within* the popup, which you launch via `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate`. This is to handle desktop, web, and mobile device scenarios properly.

Of course, the best place to start is with the docs, like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso), but unfortunately these mostly still refer to ADAL, which is being deprecated, instead of MSAL. So, as an alternative, I'd suggest looking at this recent [PnP sample for MSAL authentication](https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/tab-aad-msal2). I'm currently working on an SSO sample for this PnP repo - it's still in progress, and especially the docs are not complete, but you can see a working dotnet sample [here](https://github.com/HiltonGiesenow/teams-dev-samples/tree/add-tabs-sso-sample/samples/tab-sso).